# Can Kidney stones cause painful ejaculation?

Tags: kidney-stones

Logically, I would assume that it could, as the relatively thick semen should push the stones out with much stronger force than plain urine.

Is there literature that discusses this? Have such symptoms been documented?

Comment: Couldn't find anything in literature, but anecdotally I had a patient tell me he passed a kidney stone while ejaculating. However for this to be the case the stone would have to already be past the ejaculatory duct (at the level of the prostate, most of the way through the urinary system). It's hard to imagine someone with a stone in their urethra being able to sustain an erection, but I suppose it's possible

Comment: Pain and pleasure are intimately linked.

Answer (score 2):

If you saw the size of Foley catheters that get inserted, and how easily they slip out again, you could guess how easily the urethra passes small stones.

There was this small study which claims that frequent intercourse increases the clearance of distal renal stones, but at least in the abstract they don't mention pain.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26142575